# how to extract string before "/>" from XML using csh?

Tags: csh

I am trying to extract all text which is present before the first occurrence  of sign "/>" using csh script.
 I tried the following code

set product3 = `echo "$product1" | sed 's/\/>$//'`

bt the output I am getting is the string exist before last occurrence of "/>"

please help !!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "bt its giving the string exist ...". Please edit your script and paste in the exacct error message you're getting.  You don't really have 2 '=' signs in your `set ` statement do you? It would also really help if you included your definition of `product1` in your question above, then we could test on our own computers. Finally, is it correct to say another statment of your problem is to delete all text AFTER `/>`? If so, `sed 's/\/>.*$//` seems more appropriate. Good luck.

Comment: Also see my comment re XML on this Q : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450624/script-to-find-line-in-one-file-and-replace-in-another-osx#comment20125574_14450624 . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `sed` replacement is off by just a bit:

```
% echo "<<one/><two/>/>" | sed 's/\/>.*$//'
<<one
```

using the `.*` will cause sed to greedily consume all the characters from the first match until the end of the string, which I think is what you want.